# TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role (help)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Error: `/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/PermissionOverwriteManager.js:96
if (!userOrRole) throw new TypeError('INVALID_TYPE', 'parameter', 'User nor a Role');
^
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied parameter is not a User nor

This is the error ^^

Code:

```
          let findRole = this.client.utils.findRole(message.guild, config.roles.support[i]);
        c.permissionOverwrites.create(findRole, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] add some details what do you do and what do you want to get

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.